# Modal buttons not working on form

Tags: delphi, modal-dialog, delphi-10-seattle

I am showing a form using a `TActionManager` like this :

```
procedure TForm2.actAddImagineExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addImagineForm.Show;
end;
```

This is how the form looks like:
[image]

- It contains the following: 3 `TButton`, 1 `TOpenDialog` and 1 `TImage`
- Button **Salveaza** (*Save*) is `Button3` and has `ModalResult` set to `mrOk`
- Button **Incarca Imagine** (*Load Image*) is `Button1`
- Button **Cancel** is `Button2`, has `Cancel` property ticked and has `ModalResult` set to `mrAbort`

**Problems:**

- When I click the `Cancel` button on the form, it does not close, basically does nothing.
- When I click the `Salveaza` button on my form, it does nothing.

The code for the *Incarca Imagine* button is this:

```
procedure TaddImagineForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  selectedFile: string;
  dlg: TOpenDialog;
begin
  selectedFile := '';
  dlg := TOpenDialog.Create(nil);
  try
    dlg.InitialDir := 'C:\';
    dlg.Filter := 'All files (*.*)|*.*';
    if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
      selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
      Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(selectedFile);
  finally
    dlg.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The code for button named *Salveaza* (**Button3**) is:

```
procedure TaddImagineForm.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Field: TBlobField;
  Stream: TStream;
begin
  if dbmodule.comenziQuery.Active and (Image1.Picture.Graphic <> nil) then
  begin
    dbmodule.comenziQuery.Insert;
    Field := TBlobField(dbmodule.comenziQuery.FieldByName('pscreen')); // ensure it ís a blob
    Stream := dbmodule.comenziQuery.CreateBlobStream(Field, bmWrite);
    try
      Image1.Picture.Graphic.SaveToStream(Stream);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
      dbmodule.comenziQuery.Post;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

- The `TSQLQuery` I'm using (named *comenziQuery*) is located on a `Data module`, along with other things I'm using (like `DataSource`, `DataSet`, `SQLConnection` and so on..) the Data module is named *dbmodule*
- The column in the database that should hold the .bmp image is named **pscreen** and is set as a `mediumblob` type.

**Things I've tried:**

- I've tried adding the `close;` and `modalresult:=mrok;` but it doesn't seem to execute the code for the image, just makes the *Save* button work and closes the form but no image added to the db field
- Searched for tutorials on this, found a bunch but either they're not for what I need or I clearly don't understand how to overcome this and get it to work

Comment: You've only stated your problems in the bottom third of your post. I appreciate you've tried to include all possible information. But your actual question is hidden, buried in a mountain of irrelevance. And the title of your question ***has absolutely nothing*** to do with your _actual problems_.

Comment: @CraigYoung I've actually just noticed that, probably got carried away in trying to organize the information. The problem was the modal buttons not working, which the answer bellow fixed - now it seems the code I'm using to upload the bmp doesn't do anything (doesn't add anything to the field) so I guess I'll close this and open a new, specific question for that matter. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is the action

```
procedure TForm2.actAddImagineExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addImagineForm.Show;
end;
```

which should be

```
procedure TForm2.actAddImagineExecute(Sender: TObject);
begin
  addImagineForm.ShowModal;
end;
```

for the modal buttons to have any meaning.

### Edit

and additional problem is the lines

```
        if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
          selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
          Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(selectedFile);
```

Your indentation suggests that Image1 will attempt to load only if dlg executes successfully. This is not the case. It will always attempt to load. Your code should be

```
if dlg.Execute(Handle) then
begin
selectedFile := dlg.FileName;
Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(selectedFile);
end;
```

### Edit2

As per your comment/request

```
procedure TaddImagineForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    begin
      Image1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    end;
end;
```

Comment: lol, now I feel embarrassed. Yup, that definitely worked, Cancel and Save buttons are now working. Would I need to add something else anywhere in my code, or just this change you mentioned and that's it? Also it seems that the code for loading the img does nothing and it doesn't load the bmp to the blob field, but I guess I'll have to open a new question for that issue, right? Thank you, a lot :)

Comment: Yes, that should be all you need, and yes, you should open a new question. Please accept this answer. One thing I would question, though, is why you create a TOpenDlg on the fly, when you have a TOpenDlg on the form? Please see my edit for an additional problem.

Comment: Yup, will accept and open a new question for the blob problem. Isn't the code I'm using, using the TOpenDialog on the form? That was my impression. Like I mentioned, using tutorials from the net so probably that's why, as you say, I'm creating a new one.

Comment: No, the code you are using does not use the dialog on the form. You don't need any of the code for dlg. Instead you just need **if OpenDialog1.Execute then** and that is it. No creation, no try...finally, and no Handle. Can you see my edit now? I wrote it after I wrote the comment

Comment: Yes, I can see the edit. Thank you, made necessary modifications. Thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @tcsh This is why it is useful to try to create a [mcve].

Comment: @J... - Minimal and Complete shouldn't be in the same sentence ^_^ .. I've started reading that, thanks! :)

Comment: @tcsh - yes they should. Complete means we could use the code in our compilers to reproduce your problem. Minimal means no extra flim-flam not relevant to your problem that will simply confuse us or make things harder. The two are not in any way contradictory.

Comment: @Dsm - meant that statement as a joke :P I do appreciate the link, clarify's things up.

Comment: @tcsh sorry - sense of humour bypass! :-)